# Unity Android Screen Glitch

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a bug plaguing my project that I can't find any resources to online. There are 2 scenes in my app, Menu and Game. Menu has this behavior 100% of the time, whereas Game only loads with this glitch occasionally. It appears that once it happens once in Game, it will happen multiple times consecutively, and then eventually fix itself. Here is the image of what I am seeing: [Menu scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iMSf.jpg) --- [Game scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqFQi.jpg)

There are no scripts on my Canvas that are not standard Unity scripts, everything is stock. I have also checked the logcat log via command prompt and no errors are thrown.

If you have any information as to why this glitch is happening, please let me know. I think it has something to do with Canvas settings or a missing dependency/package conflict, but no settings that I changed caused the glitch to go away. Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: post your scripts

Comment: There are no scripts that would affect what is happening, if I disable every custom script in the project it still happens. This is a build issue, dependency issue, or a bug with the editor/engine.

Comment: could be a bug , but bugs of applications of a simple nature are extremely rare, I don't know what you mean by 'build issue', if its a dependency issue the project just won't compile, what unity version are you using? are you testing in editor or on a device?

Comment: I am testing on a device, OnePlus 6T. Has been tested on a Samsung S20 and does the same behavior. To clarify, 'dependency issue' really meant a conflict between some packages I am using. Excuse me if my terminology has been off, I really don't know how to classify what is happening here, nor do I know what is causing it at all.

Comment: whats the settings of your canvas?

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/S6qvf3S

I've changed them around to no real effect, which makes me think there is some package conflict.

Comment: ok I posed an answer , something to try

Answer (score 1):

Change UI Scale mode of canvas to scale with screen size instead of constant pixel size

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately this did not fix the issue. I will have to thoroughly begin to separate each element of my project until the problem goes away, then I can narrow down the issue to a specific package. If you have more suggestions, please suggest them. Otherwise, I think I have enough info to narrow down the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.

If you are making an AR app and have UI in the app, you NEED a regular Unity Camera in the scene alongside your AR Camera. The AR Camera should be tagged 'Main'.

For some reason, UI cannot attach to AR cameras, and while I don't understand why, the solution still works.